# Querying 4 columns with as statement syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, with-statement

I'm trying to query 4 columns with the 'with as' but keep saying my syntax is wrong (error 1064).

There are 2 tables, submissions and hackers.

```
with counter_table(s_date, h_id, h_name, counter) as 
(select s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name, count(distinct s.submission_id)
from submissions s
inner join hackers h on h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id
group by s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name);
```

I was expecting a counter_table with 4 columns: submission date, hacker name, hacker id and the counter of the submissions

Comment: OK you have created the cte now you have to select from it.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Answer (score 0):

Your current columns names with common table expressions seem wrong, and also you need to select from this **CTE** table i.e from **counter_table** like this-

```
WITH counter_table(submission_date, hacker_id, hacker_name, counter) AS 
(
    SELECT s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.submission_id) 
    FROM submissions s 
    INNER JOIN hackers h ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
    GROUP BY s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name
)
SELECT * FROM counter_table;
```

**See More:** [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20parenthesized%20list%20of%20names%20follows%20the%20CTE%20name%2C%20those%20names%20are%20the%20column%20names%3A)

Comment: Wrote it like this:
with counter_table(day, id, name, counter) AS 
(
    SELECT s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.submission_id) 
    FROM submissions s 
    INNER JOIN hackers h ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
    GROUP BY s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name
)
SELECT * FROM counter_table;

But still the same error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ... right syntax to use near 'counter_table(data, id, name, counter) AS 
(
    SELECT s.submission_date, s.hac' at line 1

Comment: No, same error.... If I write it without the 'with' statement it's ok, but when I changed to inside of the with statement the error occurs

Comment: @joao_neves_98 Please always provide the **complete** error message, (Because I do not see an error in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/-K8Qm0i2))

Comment: @joao_neves_98 And, Please, try not to write code in comments. When you question needs more clarification, you can do an [edit], and add the new info